# Finding the derivative of an integral of a continous function

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm struggling with this question - Given g(t), I need to find F'(x).
$$
\displaystyle 
   g(t) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{lll}
                \displaystyle 7 + \frac{ \sin t }{ t } & , & t \ne 0 \\
                              8                   & , & t = 0
          \end{array} \right.
$$
$$
  F(x)  = \int_{ 0 }^{ x^{2} -6 x } g(t) \, dt
$$
Here's what I got so far: 
  I noticed that the function is continuous since $\frac{ \sin t }{ t }$ will approach 1 as t approaches 0. I don't believe I can derive using $$ \frac{d}{d(x)}\int_{ u(x) }^{ v(x) } f(t) \,dt = v'(x)*f(v(x))-u'(x)*f(u(x))$$
  can I? (I've tried and it didn't work out).    I've tried using Newton-Liebnitz  - $$
F(x) = g(x^2-6x)-g(0) = \frac{\sin(x^2-6x)}{x^2-6x} -1 $$ then deriving individually but I got the wrong result. What's the strategy for these? Do you know of any website that can check excersizes similar to this one? (where g(t) is made up of different terms depending on t's value). Did I make a calculation error or an error due to lack of understanding something? I'm really struggling with this subject.

 Thanks!

Comment: You are misusing the Fundamental theorem of calculus. $F(x)$ is not $g(x^2-6x)-g(0)$; this is true if you use a capital $G$, for $G$ a valid indefinite integral/antiderivative of $g$. But what about $F’$?

Comment: By Chain Rule and FTC  $F'(x)=g(x)\frac d {dx} (x^{2}-6x)$

Comment: by chain rule are you refering to  $$ \frac{d}{d(x)}\int_{ u(x) }^{ v(x) } f(t) \,dt = v'(x)*f(v(x))-u'(x)*f(u(x))$$ ? In that case shouldn't it be  $F'(x)=g(x^2-6x)\frac d {dx} (x^{2}-6x)$ - can you explain it in a bit more detail please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using $\frac{d}{d(x)}\int_{ u(x) }^{ v(x) } f(t) \,dt = v'(x)*f(v(x))-u'(x)*f(u(x))$ 
 on 
$F(x)  = \int_{ 0 }^{ x^{2} -6 x } g(t) \, dt$

we get: $$ F'(x) = g(x^2 - 6x)*\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-6x) - g(0)*\frac{d}{dx}(0)$$
the left term cancels out since the derivative of 0 is 0, and the right term is the solution. so -
$$F'(x) = g(x^2 - 6x)*\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-6x) $$
$$F'(x) =\left(7+\frac{\sin\!\left(x^{2}-6x\right)}{x^{2}-6x}\right)\!\left(2x-6\right)$$